# What am i doing wrong in Conda?

Tags: bash, anaconda, conda

I am a first time user of of Anaconda & Miniconda suite and I have been having problems running code using it.  Every time I try to run a python script in Anaconda or miniconda it comes up with this issue:

```
/miniconda3/lib/libtinfo.so.6: no version information available (required by /bin/bash)
/anaconda3/lib/libtinfo.so.6: no version information available (required by /bin/bash)
```

I have looked in all the help documents and in my directory and the file is there and symlink to both `libtinfo.so.6.2` and `libtinfo.so.6`

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

I stumbled across the same problem.

Here is some relevant information about what is happening:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38851073
It seems that the libtinfo shared library shipped with conda does not provide its version information. So it's a problem on their end.

I was able to workaround the problem by using another shared library of the same `libtinfo.so` with the same version as the one shipped with conda and that contains the version information.
For instance in my case:

```
rm ${CONDA_PREFIX}/lib/libtinfo*
ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.6 ${CONDA_PREFIX}/lib/libtinfo.so.6
```

Comment: it broke use of `nano`: 

`nano: error while loading shared libraries: libtinfow.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
`

Answer (score 0):

To get *libtinfo.so.6* library installed you have to install [single package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=amd64&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=libtinfo.so.6) by

```
sudo apt-get install libtinfo6
```

and then retry launching Conda.

Comment: Tried that it has something to do with the link between libtinfo and libtinfo.so/libtinfo.so.6

Comment: so, did it work?